# Angular CLI AOT build error cache?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, aot

I have an Angular (2) app that is failing to build using the AOT compiler. What's strange is I nuked the component with the error and rebuilt from the ground up adding one line at a time so I could trace the issue (the AOT error is completely useless). As I rebuilt suddenly the error appeared, so I removed the last thing I added and for some reason the error persisted. I then went so far as to take the component all the way back to the basic structure provided by the Angular CLI but the error message persisted. Any idea what's happening? See below for the component in it's current does-nothing state which is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR in /PATH_REMOVED/$$_gendir/app/dashboard-chart/dashboard-chart.component.ngfactory.ts (49,9): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Using this build command

```
ng serve --aot --prod
```

dashboard-chart.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-chart',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-chart.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @ViewChild('chart') chartContainer: ElementRef;
    @Input() data: any[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnChanges() {

    }

}
```

dashboard-component.html

```
<div class="d3-chart" #chart></div>
```

Comment: Im assuming you're using this component somewhere like this '<dashboard-chart [data]="someArray"> <dashboard-chart>' did you check to see that 'someArray' is actually of type array? I think thats the issue you are passing something that is not of type 'any[]' also whats the cli version you're using?

Comment: My experience with `ng serve` has been that at times you need to kill it, and restart it, because it will not move past an error that I know isn't valid. Sometimes, simply adding a new property to an interface can put it in an unreliable mode.

Comment: I did have another component using the dashboard-chart selector, but I removed it to test since I assumed it had something to do with it.

Comment: Ya, thought that too. I restarted the ng server and the error was still there. Also did ng build --aot with the same result.

Comment: Also, the component works fine with JIT compilation.

Comment: What version of angular-cli? And are your global and local versions matching?